# Bypassing dead relatives Apple ID?

Tags: ipad, icloud, password

My Auntie died unexpectedly without leaving her icloud information (pretty standard!) I've restored her ipad as I thought it would reset her passcode as I couldn't guess it but now it's asking for Apple ID. I've tried everything but I can't guess her secret info or get into her emails until I go see my grandad and get her phone (he literally lives at the other side of the country.) So now I have this ipad and my cousin has iPod touch which is acting as a paper weight. There must be a way around it as this must be a fairly common thing surely? I don't have her death certificate, there isn't a will and my grandad (next of Kin) is 86 and quite flustered about everything and he's about had enough.

Ive looked online for a bypass but no luck, as it's not reported stolen surely it can't have an anti theft lock? 
Thank you

Comment: Passwords and IDs are not intended to be bypassed otherwise what is the purpose of having them. Since the iPad is operational, not locked, what is it you are after?

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that you will need to prove to Apple what has happened. EG you are now the legal owner of the iPad and have legal access to her account.

Call Applecare and ask them what the procedure is for these circumstances. I suspect (if they can help) it may involve a death certificate, a copy of the will and a notarized letter from the executor of the estate giving you access.

But then I am guessing...

Comment: Here's in article describing almost same events...http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-26448158  Looks like you need what was mention above to get it reset.

Answer (score 2):

We called Apple Store in Trafford in a similar case and got told that a Death certificate and Probate document would need to be brought to them along with the iPad by a "legal representative"

When questioned as to what a "legal representative" meant it seemed that a "Solicitor / Lawyer / Barrister" was what they wanted.  Would cost more than replacing the iPad with a new one.

Answer (score 1):

direct from apple "help" ::

1. The death certificate
2. A court document that confirms that the requestor is the decedent's 
   legal personal representative
3. United States: The court must notarize or certify all documents.

NOTE:  Can not be a will a trust or a power of attorney