# How do I obtain my dead husband's password for his iPhone?

Tags: iphone, password

My husband died.  I have the death certificate.  Also using his iPhone.  Don't have his password.  Would like to obtain it.  How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe just contact Apple?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, with a court order, or notarised will, etc, presented to Apple.
There have been many tales online of that being the only way.

I found an SE reference, linking a BBC report - [Bypassing dead relatives Apple ID?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150517/bypassing-dead-relatives-apple-id)